# partprobe for udev Format File System

Tags: partitioning, systemd, udev, udisks

I have a script that runs a `mkfs` right before `udisksctl mount -b ...` on a device. Problem is that if I don't put a `sleep` in between them `udev` doesn't realize it's been formatted something that can be mounted yet and so it gives an error saying the partition is not mountable.

I know about `udevadm settle --timeout=15 --exit-if-exists=$PARTITION`. However, that only check if a file exists or not but I need to check to see if the file system format has been updated.

I've tried `partprobe` with no success. Also, I'd like to add that even without `partprobe` the `mount` command still works to mount the drive immediately after formatting it. Meaning that this is confirmed a `udev` problem.

Any guidance would be much appreciated, thank you.